# Project has dependencies in maven that are not resolved locally (Spring-security dependencies)

Tags: spring, maven, spring-security

I try to use Spring, but it seems some problem in my pom.xml, where it is unable to resolve spring dependencies.

In pom.xml I have the following repository:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repository.springframework.maven.release</id>
        <name>Spring Framework Maven Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<!-- Spring Core framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> 
        <!-- Spring security framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

I Got always : Could not resolve dependencies for project, The following artifacts could not be resolved:

```
 org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.1.2.RELEASE
aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0
org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.1.2.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE
org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.1.2.RELEASE
```

Even If I use another repository in pom.xml or even delete the repository to use the default one from maven, it the same, nothing changed.

Full error message from Maven:

```
Failed to execute goal on project Aegyptologie: Could not resolve dependencies for project de.unileipzig.wirote:Aegyptologie:war:0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE, org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.1.2.RELEASE, aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0, org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.1.2.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE, org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.1.2.RELEASE: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE from/to repository.springframework.maven.release (http://maven.springframework.org/release): Connection reset -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Could you please provide the entire error message from Maven?

Comment: @A_Di-Matteo No, I don't use any proxy

Comment: @Daniel I edit my question. See please the entire error in the edited question

Comment: Have you any reason for not fetching Spring framework from maven central? I have never used `http://maven.springframework.org/release`...

Comment: @javaHelper see the log for -X clean install goals: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c8sjwdf73b9t4yf/-X%20clean-install.txt?dl=0

Comment: @javaHelper I used older releases as you suggested, but nothing changed. pom.xml: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lf69tznczg9akom/pom.xml?dl=0

Comment: @SergeBallesta How can get the spring framework from maven central? please check my pom.xml: dropbox.com/s/lf69tznczg9akom/pom.xml?dl=0

Comment: What happens if you remove the block `<repositories>...</repositories>`?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I tried it before, nothing changed!!

Comment: Could you please share your web.xml ? I was able to build project successfully with your pom.xml file

Comment: @javaHelper see the web.xml also other file of my project in the github: https://github.com/ralmoued/Aegyptologie/tree/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can build the project without any error. Please see the logs as an evidence: It looks to me that you're running behind the proxy. If yes, you need to fixed the conf/settings.xml file of apache-maven-3.x.x

```
$ mvn clean install -DskipTests
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Aegyptologie 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/4.1.2.RELEASE/spring-security-web-4.1.2.RELEASE.pom
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/4.1.2.RELEASE/spring-security-web-4.1.2.RELEASE.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/4.1.2.RELEASE/spring-security-web-4.1.2.RELEASE.pom (0 B at 0.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/4.1.2.RELEASE/spring-security-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.pom
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/4.1.2.RELEASE/spring-security-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/4.1.2.RELEASE/spring-security-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.pom (0 B at 0.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/4.1.2.RELEASE/spring-security-web-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar
Downloading: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/4.1.2.RELEASE/spring-security-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/4.1.2.RELEASE/spring-security-web-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/4.1.2.RELEASE/spring-security-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/4.1.2.RELEASE/spring-security-web-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar (0 B at 0.0 KB/sec)
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/4.1.2.RELEASE/spring-security-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar (0 B at 0.0 KB/sec)
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ Aegyptologie ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Aegyptologie ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 29 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Aegyptologie ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 42 source files to e:\Advance Java\POI\Aegyptologie\target\classes
[WARNING] /e:/Advance Java/POI/Aegyptologie/src/main/java/de/unileipzig/wirote/control/Encoding.java: e:\Advance Java\POI\Aegyptologie\src\main\java\de\unileipzig\wirote\control\Encoding.java uses unchecked or uns
[WARNING] /e:/Advance Java/POI/Aegyptologie/src/main/java/de/unileipzig/wirote/control/Encoding.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Aegyptologie ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory e:\Advance Java\POI\Aegyptologie\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Aegyptologie ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ Aegyptologie ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ Aegyptologie ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [Aegyptologie] in [e:\Advance Java\POI\Aegyptologie\target\awv-seite]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [e:\Advance Java\POI\Aegyptologie\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [6184 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: e:\Advance Java\POI\Aegyptologie\target\awv-seite.war
[INFO] WEB-INF\web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ Aegyptologie ---
[INFO] Installing e:\Advance Java\POI\Aegyptologie\target\awv-seite.war to C:\Users\prateek\.m2\repository\de\unileipzig\wirote\Aegyptologie\0.1-SNAPSHOT\Aegyptologie-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Installing e:\Advance Java\POI\Aegyptologie\pom.xml to C:\Users\prateek\.m2\repository\de\unileipzig\wirote\Aegyptologie\0.1-SNAPSHOT\Aegyptologie-0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 42.299 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-08-19T01:49:13+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 29M/320M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I am using netbeans abs IDE and default setting : no Proxy. I tested the connection and is worked fine

Answer (score 0):

In a standalone pure Spring project, always try to use the same versions of the framework module to avoid incompatibility issues. Otherwise use Spring Boot if u don't want to manage dependencies yourself. But this should work fine.